# Is this a good way to store date eligibility per customer in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to calculate discount for a customer and apply this to their account on a monthly basis.  The rule is simply that the customer must have two or more supplies to be eligible for the discount each day.

Some customers have simple histories, they start their account with two supplies on the same date and end both supplies on the same date.

Many customers have a more complicated history, they can start with a single supply, change this to two supplies for a short period, then back to a single supply again, with any variation of this theme.

My current solution is very, very simple.  I have a table called [DiscountDays] that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [DiscountDays] (
    AccountNumber NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,    
    DiscountDate DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AccountNumber, DiscountDate));
```

There is a daily process that runs as follows:

- For each customer work out if they are eligible for discount today (have two products supplied today).  If they are then add a row to the [DiscountDays] table with their account number and today's date;
- If the customer isn't eligible for discount today then do nothing.

On completion I simply extract the total number of discount days accrued for each customer from the [DiscountDays] table and use this to work out how much discount they should have been paid.  I can easily find out how much discount they have been paid to date.  If they are owed some discount then this results in a new payment being created at the end of the month.

I also have to handle losses and other complications, but the basic model works well for every situation I have thrown at it so far.

Now some facts and figures:

- This discount first became available on 01-Jan-2014;
- There are currently 27,916,572 rows in the [DiscountDays] table;
- This is across a customer base of 83,376 customers who have been eligible for at least one day's discount.

The obvious change here would be to store non-contiguous date periods instead.  For example, let's say a customer is eligible for the discount on 01-Jan-2014 and was eligible until 10-May-2015.  They then had a period with a single supply and then went back to being eligible again on 10-Aug-2015.

The old method would be to store a row of data for each date of eligibility, i.e. 495 + 4 = 499 rows.

The new method would be to store two rows of data:

```
Account Number,Start Date, End Date
1234567,01-Jan-2014,10-May-2015
1234567,10-Aug-2015,13-Aug-2015
```

I can see that this new method would greatly reduce the amount of data being stored, but it has the immediate disadvantage of being much more complicated.

I like the original solution, even though it was meant as a placeholder, because it is so simple to follow.  It also seems to perform really, really well.

This is SQL-Server 2014.

My question is, am I making a future problem for myself storing the data in a way that is going to end up creating many millions of rows of data.  Should I bite the bullet now and move to the new solution instead?

Also, if I do stick with the original solution, are there any "tricks" I can use to make it more scalable?  The only idea I have had so far is to convert the Account Number into an integer key (using a lookup table) to reduce the storage required for each row.

Edit - I removed the original version of my table, the one where I allowed NULL values and used a UNIQUE CLUSTERED index as a pseudo-PRIMARY KEY, because primary keys don't allow NULL values.

This was causing a lot of discussion and I don't want to get into an argument over whether NULLable PRIMARY KEYs is a good thing or not.  Instead I would like to concentrate on my original question...

My take is that Edgar Codd originally intended all database columns to be NULLable and that the rule that a PRIMARY KEY can't allow NULLable columns was an artificial rule, added partly because of misunderstandings and partly due to technical limitations a the time.  But this rule has stuck and now people "think" that this actually makes sense!

In general I create all of my databases with no PRIMARY KEYs, using UNIQUE CLUSTERED indexes instead.  This works fine with FOREIGN KEY constraints, preventing duplicates, etc.  However, I can also understand why some people find this approach disturbing, as it doesn't fit their perceived rules on database design.

Comment: I find your "don't do primary keys" statement odd.  They don't allow null values because nulls don't help identify your rows.  In any case, my first attempt at applying your discount logic would be in a view.  Then, you aren't processing and persisting this information and it would always be up to date.  And, if the logic changes, you just update your view and don't need to reprocess all of your data.  Of course, performance could become a factor which might make processing/storage more attractive.

Comment: You might get downvote because this question is more suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity what makes you think this question should be asked on dba.stackexchange ???

Comment: @M.Ali I didn't down-voted it but I believe SO for databases are related to programming while dba is open for database design, structure and planning too.

Comment: Anyway I know you need a stored procedure to place orders, which inserts a row in the `DiscountDays` for that customer for that day and then insert a row in orders table and then finally when calculating price see if there are two rows for that user for that particular date in `DiscountDays` table , if there are then apply discount otherwise just proceed as usual.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity yea I guess you are right but this question will need a code fix to solve the problem hence I think it is eligible to be asked on SO. its only my opinion I could be wrong :)

Comment: Your comment about PK is odd (what if you want to build a FK from this table to another with a single column? Composite key columns have caveats for FK scenarios) but the design of storing a row for each date is odd as well.  A common scenario is using a date range on 2 columns and calling them StartEffectiveDate and EndEffectiveDate.  Both of these columns can be indexed, so searching on them is pretty efficient.

Comment: The part about nullable fields in option one, what is the situation where or why either of those fields would be null.  If it null, there is not discount and perhaps no need for the record to exist anyway.  In Option 2, your primary key is your account and your start date.  If the discount never starts, it never happens, if the end is null that could mean it never ends.

Comment: You're working with databases and you don't "do" primary keys? let alone understand them!

Comment: @Nick, I see you come from an Oracle background, so I will try to ignore your obvious troll.  Maybe you should to a bit of reading about the early history of relational databases before jumping to conclusions about what I do or don't know?  I am going to guess that your database experience comes from a textbook, so I suppose that explains your lack of insight?

Comment: Apologies for my rude comment. However I spend a lot of time fixing technical debt and data quality issues introduced by people who don't "do" database stuff, so I find those kind of statements particularly vexing.